# Kommata mit zwei Konjunktionen, die nebeneinander stehen

Tags: comma

Können Sie mir bitte sagen, ob diese Kommata, an denen ich zweifle, dort sein sollen?

1. Meine Freundin aß meine Pampelmuse und meine köstlichen Nüsse, aber **(,)** wenn ich ihr gesagt hätte, dass diese Sachen meine sind, hätte sie sie nicht gegessen, denke ich.
2. Ich sagte meinem Feind, dass **(,)** wenn er mich angreift, ich ihn verletzen werde.

Comment: Deine Sätze enthielten noch andere Fehler, die ich korrigiert habe: Das Wort köstlich ist kein Substantiv, sondern ein Adjektiv, daher darf man es mitten im Satz nicht mit einem großen Anfangsbuchstaben schreiben. Das Wort »Nüsse« schreibt man seit der Rechtschreibreform von 1996 nicht mehr mit ß sondern mit ss. Das Wort Sashen gibt es nicht. Ich vermute, dass damit Sachen gemeint war. Im zweiten Satz habe ich den hinteren Teil komplett geändert. Im deutschsprachigen ...

Comment: ... Raum töten wir niemanden, nur weil er uns angreift. Wir lösen Konflikte anders. Und wenn du »мыслитель« (Denker) in deinem Namen führst, solltest du das eigentlich auch so sehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das Wort "Nüsse" hat man auch schon vor der Rechtschreibreform nicht mit "ß", sondern immer schon mit "ss" geschrieben, weil es ein echter Doppelkonsonant ist. "Nüsse" schreibt man so, weil das hypothetische "Nüse" wie "Düse" ausgesprochen würde, Während zB "Maße" keineswegs wie "Masse" ausgesprochen wird, aber das "s" - im Gegensatz zum hypothetischen "Mase" - betont wird. Und daß wir "Konflikte anders lösen", darüber denken "im deutschsprachigen Raum" vermutlich Juden, Roma, Sinti, kärntner Slowenen und andere unterschiedlich.

Comment: @bakunin: Du hast recht,  die Pluralform "Nüsse" wurde immer schon mit Doppel-S geschrieben. Ich habe mich da von der Singular-Form fehlleiten lassen, die zwischen 1901 und 1996 mit einem scharfem S geschrieben wurde ("Nuß"). Vor 1901 und nach 1996 ist "Nuss" richtig. - Warum dichtest du ausgerechnet Juden, Roma, Sinti und Kärntner Slowenen Gewaltbereitschaft an? In meiner Wahrnehmung sind das genau jene Bevölkerungsgruppen, die Gewalt erdulden mussten. Deren Gegenwehr bestand nur selten darin die Angreifer zu töten.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: ich "dichte" nicht "ausgerechnet Juden, Roma, Sinti und Kärntner Slowenen Gewaltbereitschaft an", sondern behauptete, daß diese Volksgruppen Lieder davon singen können, daß "wir" eben NICHT - wie von Dir im Kommentar behauptet - "niemanden [töten], nur weil er uns angreift", sondern eben sehr wohl töten, oft genug auch ohne die Vorbedingung des Angriffs, sondern aus purer Lust an der Freude. "Wir" lösen Konflikte eben nicht "anders", sondern genau so wie von Dir wegeditiert.

Answer (score 1):

Grundsätzlich gilt, dass das Wort *»wenn«* dafür verwendet wird, einen untergeordneten Nebensatz (eine Subjunktion) einzuleiten, und solche Subjunktionen müssen im Normalfall von Kommas umschlossen sein. Daher kann man sich merken, dass vor der Subjunktion *»wenn«* ein Komma stehen muss.

Die Subjunktion *wenn* bildet aber mit manchen Konjunktionen und Adverbien feste Fügungen. Dann leitet nicht das Wort *»wenn«* alleine die Subjunktion ein, sondern die ganze Fügung übernimmt dann diese einleitende Rolle. In diesem Fall rutscht das Komma, das eigentlich vor dem Wort *»wenn«* stehen sollte, vor die Fügung. Hier sind ein paar Beispiele:

> Ich mache meine Hausaufgaben, **aber erst wenn** ich mit dem Essen fertig bin.
> Ich gehe da sicher nicht hin, **selbst wenn** man mir viel Geld dafür zahlen würde.
> Es scheint so, **als wenn** er immer schon vorher wüsste, was wir vorhaben.

Die beiden Wörter *»aber«* und *»wenn«* bilden eine solche Fügung. Die beiden Wörter *»dass«* und *»wenn«* jedoch nicht. Daher darf zwischen *»aber«* und *»wenn«* kein Komma stehen, zwischen *»dass«* und *»wenn«* muss aber eines stehen.

Richtig sind daher diese beiden Sätze:

> 1. Meine Freundin aß meine Pampelmuse und meine köstlichen Nüsse, **aber wenn** ich ihr gesagt hätte, dass diese Sachen meine sind, hätte sie sie nicht gegessen, denke ich.
> 2. Ich sagte meinem Feind, **dass, wenn** er mich angreift, ich ihn verletzen werde.

---

**Verbesserungen deiner Sätze**

> Meine Freundin aß meine Pampelmuse und meine köstlichen Nüsse, aber wenn ich ihr gesagt hätte, dass diese **Köstlichkeiten mir gehören,** hätte sie sie **vermutlich** nicht gegessen.

- Sachen → Köstlichkeiten
  Wörter wie *Sachen* und *Dinge* sollte man, wann immer es möglich ist, vermeiden und durch spezifischere Begriffe ersetzen.
- meine sind → mir gehören
  Im Deutschen ziehen wir die Formulierung "das gehört mir" gegenüber der Formulierung "das ist meines" vor. Grammatisch sind beide korrekt, aber deutsche Muttersprachler verwenden häufiger "das gehört mir".
- denke ich → vermutlich
  Hier sollte ausgedrückt werden, dass der Sprecher eine Vermutung hat. Dafür gibt es im Deutschen ein eigenes Wort, nämlich das Modaladverb *»vermutlich«.* Aber Vorsicht: Wenn man *»denke ich«* durch *»vermutlich«* ersetzt, verliert man die Information, wer diese Vermutung anstellt. In den meisten Fällen lässt sich diese Information aber aus dem Kontext schließen, und in den meisten Fällen ist diese Information auch nicht so wichtig.

> Ich sagte meinem Feind, dass ich ihn verletzen werde, wenn er mich angreift.

Es ist zwar nicht falsch, den Nebensatz, der mit *»wenn«* beginnt, in den anderen Nebensatz einzufügen, aber dadurch entstehen tiefe Verschachtelungen, die es schwer machen, den Satz zu verstehen. Solche Verschachtelungen sorgen dann manchmal auch dafür, dass man mit der Kommasetzung durcheinander kommt. Daher sollte man diese Nebensätze lieber hintereinander schreiben statt sie zu verschachteln.