# Komma bei Infinitiv mit "zu" fakultativ oder obligatorisch?

Tags: subordinate-clause, comma

Ich bin auf diese Frage bei der Lektüre von [Kommata mit zwei Konjunktionen, die nebeneinander stehen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73413/kommata-mit-zwei-konjunktionen-die-nebeneinander-stehen) gestoßen. Dort wird unter anderem auf die Frage [Können Verben Bezug auf eine Infinitivgruppe nehmen? Komma fakultativ oder obligatorisch?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/k%C3%B6nnen-verben-bezug-auf-eine-infinitivgruppe-nehmen-komma-fakultativ-oder-oblig?rq=1) verwiesen. In der dort akzeptierten Antwort von @Wrzlprmft wird als Beispiel aus §78(3) zitiert:

> Er beabsichtigte(,) nach seiner Ausbildung ein Studium aufzunehmen.

Ich frage mich (bzw. - euch), ob das Komma hier wirklich fakultativ ist. Hier sind zwei Varianten:

> Er beabsichtigte, nach seiner Ausbildung ein Studium aufzunehmen.
> Er beabsichtigte nach seiner Ausbildung, ein Studium aufzunehmen.

Stünde dieser Satz ohne Komma da, so wäre nicht klar, welche der beiden Varianten gemeint ist - es könnten beide der Fall sein. Trat die Absicht nach der Ausbildung ein und hat er sich vorher keine Gedanken gemacht oder war die Absicht schon während seiner Ausbildung vorhanden und bestand darin, nach der Ende der Ausbildung ein Studium aufzunehmen?

Mir kommt das ein wenig vor, wie:

> Wir essen Oma!
> Wir essen, Oma!

Eingedenk des Umstands, daß Interpunktion - wenigstens in diesem Fall - Leben retten kann, wäre ich für Hinweise dankbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hier greift m. E. aus den zitierten Rechtschreibregeln, § 75, Absatz 3:

> (3) Der Schreibende kann durch das Komma deutlich machen, ob er Wörter als Bestandteil der Nebensatzeinleitung verstanden wissen will oder nicht:

> Ich freue mich, auch wenn du mir nur eine Karte schreibst.

gegenüber

> Ich freue mich auch, wenn du mir nur eine Karte schreibst.

Da auch hier **kann** steht, ist es immer noch fakultativ, selbst wenn der Satz dann mehrdeutig bleibt.